# Using specific command output of JSch to trigger next command

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  String user = "XXXXX";       
  String host = "XXXXX"; 
  String passwd = "XXXXX";      
  int port = 22;    
  Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
  session.setPassword(passwd);
  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
  session.connect();

  Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
  OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
  PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

  channel.connect();

  //commands
  ps.println("sudo su - user");
  ps.println("ls | wc -l");

  ps.println("pwd");

  ps.println("exit");
  ps.close();

  channel.disconnect();
  session.disconnect();
 }
```

for this kind of code, is it possible:

1. Get the output for each command fired on the console individually.
2. Use a control statement depending upon the previous output.

e.g: If I use

```
ls | wc -l
```

The output would be a fixed digit as the directories in root wouldn't change. Using this number to either process step a or b using if/else condition.

Comment: You might want "tee"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this awhile ago, but I did it a little differently then how you have it setup. It grabs the returns how you would like and all that though.

**Edit**: I updated the code, so the username, host, and password can easily be set pragmatically. It then loops through an array of commands, checking the return with the ability to execute another command or continue on.

Here's the code with a few extra comments (hopefully helpful)

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Properties;

public class cmdExec
{
  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    try
    {
      JSch jsch = new JSch();

      String user = "<username>";
      String host = "<host>";
      String paswrd = "<password>";

      Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

      Properties config = new Properties();
      config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

      session.setPassword(paswrd);

      session.setConfig(config);
      session.connect();

      // build an array of commands to run
      String[] cmds = {"user | wc -l", "ps -ef | wc -l"};

      for(int cnt = 0; cnt < cmds.length; cnt++)
      {
        String command = cmds[cnt];

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

        channel.setInputStream(null);

        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

        while (true){

            while (in.available()>0){
              int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
              if (i < 0)
              {
                break;
              }
              // grab the return, hopefully a number
              String strRet = new String(tmp, 0, i);
              // trim whitespace and convert to int
              int ret = Integer.parseInt(strRet.trim());

              if ( ret != 1 )
              {
                System.out.println("Do something else, the return wasn't one.");
              }
              else
              {
                System.out.println("Return was 1. Continuing on...");
              }
            }
            if(channel.isClosed()){
              if(in.available()>0) continue;
              //System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
              break;
            }
            try
            {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
              // Do something with the exception
            }  
        }
        channel.disconnect();

      }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am actually trying to automate a script using java. The next command should follow immediately only after the previous exit status is [1]. While executing:

`ps.println("sudo su - app");
      ps.println("ls -lrt");
      ps.println("exit");
      ps.println("exit");ps.close();
      System.out.println(channel.getExitStatus());`
The entire code runs as a bundle. I need to capture specific outputs in a variable in java and then test it. Eclipse output:
`Connecting SSH
-1  {<- Exit status before execution}
Last login:

sudo su - app
ls -lrt
exit
exit`

Comment: @Jazz I updated the code to better show how to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks mate. This solved the issue, although I was looking forward to passing more commands to the console. The commands sent via: "String[] cmds" works in a batch. After the count, the next command should replace the one being fired with the if condition.

In short: Running an entire shell script with conditions from Java in Unix. Is that possible? As the current output is just screen scrapped.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying here. I think you want to run other commands based on the return? If so there's a couple options, one being you could called a separate method inside the if condition based on the return of the previous command. Another option is to look at [how arrays work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in Java and add the command you want next to the array of commands (cmds).

Comment: I tried running `sudo su - user`. This works completely fine in the **shell** script but not in the **exec** as per the code. Could you please help me with this? Get an error: `ksh: sudo:  not found`